# Recreate git repository from remote with existing files

Tags: git, perforce

I didn't even know how to start looking for it so I ask here.

I have not so usual setup, where I pull UE4 from github and then add it to perforce depot.

Right now the git repo lives only on single computer as I don't really want to add entire .git folder to perforce. 
Now say I create another workspace on another computer and pull all files using perforce. 
In that another workspace I'd like to recreate git repo. It's probabaly not that simple as git init and git pull as I already tried it.

Please not that It is safe to override everything using git as I don't make any unmerged changes.

Comment: "*It's probably not that simple as `git init` and `git pull`*" In what way it's not?

Comment: There are already files existing which are not in git repo (obviously) and git pull cannot overwrite them.

Comment: `git init`, `git stash save`, `git pull`, `git stash pop`?